# Uploading files through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I want to be able to upload files using AJAX.

I've tried using (JavaScript):

```
   $("input[type='file']").change(function(){
        var file = document.getElementById("uploadelement").files[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name); 
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

With (PHP):

```
<?php

    $fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
    if ($fn) {
        // AJAX call
        file_put_contents(
            'uploads/' . $fn,
            file_get_contents('php://input')
        );
        echo "$fn uploaded";
        exit();
    }

?>
```

However, i'm having the issue, that the files content isn't show up. I'm not sure whats going wrong. I have found this code on a [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/) so I figured it should be working.

The file is uploaded to the folder but there is no content.

Comment: You're not sending the file, that is pretty clear after looking at your client side code.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("uploadelement").files;` instead of `document.getElementById("uploadelement").files[0];`? The `[]` brackets is usually used for multiple uploads. Might be the problem, but I couldn't be 100% sure.

Comment: @Fred `document.getElementById("uploadelement").files` just returns an array.

Comment: @RayNicholus `file_get_contents('php://input')` should get the content.

Comment: Get it from where? I repeat, you are not sending the file.

Comment: What about `file_get_contents('$fn')`? Sorry, I'm picking at straws here. I'm not well-versed with Ajax, but seeing that `$fn` is in relation to what I think is the filename.

Comment: @Fred that wouldn't work since the file isn't uploaded yet. Also since you would need double quotes to add variables in a string like that :P

Comment: I downloaded the tutorial zip file and was successful. I take it you're not using the same JS then?

Comment: I'd suggest using the formdata approach since you can use the same php code to handle an ajax upload and a form upload.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know with the jQuery `$.ajax()` call, but this can be achieved by using an `XMLHttpRequest`, like so:

```
var file = document.getElementById("uploadelement").files[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("userfile", file);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "upload.php");
xmlhttp.send(form_data);
```

Then in your PHP upload handler (upload.php in here):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "path/to/uploads/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
```

And then the file should already be saved to the desired directory.